# Is there a name for this generalisation of the exponential distribution

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, exponential-distribution

Is there a name for the following:

$$ f(x) = \lambda(x) e^{\int_0^x -\lambda(t) dt} $$

which is similar to an exponential distribution. If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, would this be classed as a gamma distribution or a Weibull distribution? Or is it neither of those?

Comment: When $f$ is a polynomial, it cannot possibly be the density of any distribution!  Generally, you appear to be describing a nonlinear transform of an exponential distribution, assuming $\lambda$ is never negative.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry I meant some kind of truncated polynomial that can't go negative (after I posted the question, I changed my mind to have lambda be an exponential function). But okay, so it's just a transform of an exponential distribution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant this to be a density function on the positive real line, I will assume that. Then, introduce some notation. Let $\lambda(x)$ be a positive function for $x\geq 0$, with integral $\Lambda(x)=\int_0^x \lambda(t) \; dt$. Then $\Lambda$ will be a positive, increasing function. In addition, assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \Lambda(x)=\infty$. ($\lambda$ could well be a positive polynomial for positive arguments, but that is not necessary). Let $\Omega$ be the inverse function to $\Lambda$.

Now let $T$ be an exponential random variable with rate 1. Thinking of $T$ as a waiting time, introduce what is sometimes called a **time change transformation** of $T$: let
$$ Y=\Omega(T) $$
Let us find the distribution of $Y$:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
   \P(Y \le y) = \P(\Omega(Y) \le y)=\P(T \le \Lambda(y) ) \\
= 1- e^{-\Lambda(y)} $$ Now by differentiation we can find the density function of $Y$ as
$$ fY(y) = \lambda(y) e^{-\Lambda(y)}. $$

**Summary** The density you ask for can be seen as the distribution of a time-changed exponential random variable.